# Hide specific swagger properties for specific endpoints from a same DTO in NestJs

Tags: swagger, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I have a Nest Js `UpdateUserDTO` with `6` properties in it, annotated with `@ApiProperty()`, and I have **three** different endpoints in my `controller`.
Now I want to use `4` of them for **endpoint 1** , `2` of them for **endpoint 2** and other `2`  of them for **endpoint 3** , but from the same `UpdateUserDTO`.

We have `@ApiHideProperty()` , that totally hides the property from swagger, also I tried to use it at controller level, but I wasn't able to make it do that, as it only works for properties inside dto.

We have `@ApiExcludeController()` and `@ApiExcludeEndpoint()`, that totally hides the controller or endpoint from swagger. But don't want that.

Is there any solution for my use case **where I can use a single DTO for different endpoints with different properties**

**Or**

DO we have any **swagger** decorator like `@ApiExcludeProperty()` , which is useable at controller level for **NestJs** `@Body()` decorator?

**Basically I want to do Hide and Display properties for different endpoints from a single DTO, I searched on internet but I wasn't able to find anything useful.**

Answer (score 3):

You can use `OmitType<DTO, ['foo']>` or `PickType(CreateCatDto, ['foo']`

You cans see this here : https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/mapped-types

There are several different types, such as Partial, Intersection etc...
An example :

```js
export class CreateUserDto extends PickType<UpdateUserDTO, ['bar']> {}
```

Comment: With this I have to create new `DTOs` for every endpoint, if I'm not mistaken? , and if I'm not, then the answer is not providing the solution for what I asked.As I stated that I don't want to create new one, because I want to use a single DTO for different endpoints with different properties. For some endpoints, some properties are visible, and for some other not visible.

Comment: Well that's not possible.
If you do this you will have model name conflicts in your swagger.
Swagger needs a particular and unique name for each model, a DTO is a model. So in this logic, you are obliged to create a new DTO for each new model. This is also indicated indirectly in the NestJS documentation.